# Function to sort an array and return the sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, custom-function

PHP's native sorting functions modify by reference and do not return the sorted array.

I am looking for a reliable standard method to sort an array, returning the sorted array as the return value.

All of the PHP.net functions I have read about return BOOLEAN value, or 0-1.

The method I need would be something like:

```
$some_mixed_array = array( 998, 6, 430 );
function custom_sort( $array )
{ 
  // Sort it
  // return sorted array
}

custom_sort( $some_mixed_array );

// returning: array( 6, 430, 998 )
```

No need to handle strings, just INT-s.

Comment: Why not sort a copy of the array using PHP functions and return the result?

Comment: Can the original array be modified or should it be left as is? If not, `function custom_sort($a) { sort($a); return $a; }`

Comment: `function custom_short($array) { asort($array); return $array }` this one?

Comment: do you mean 'short' or 'sort'? In your code you have `short`

Comment: While the sort functions return a bool they still sort your array - so what problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: The `sort(), asort(), ksort(), etc` functions actually alter the array that you pass to them, so you can simply return the exact same array after it's been sorted.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?! It seems like an excellent question, that has a nice clear answer.  As a reason to want this, you have one-liners like: `assert(sort(array_keys($myData)) == array('x','y'))` This fails with "Only variables should be passed by reference".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

`call_user_func(function(array $a){asort($a);return $a;}, $some_mixed_array);`

Answer (score 5):

Would you be able to do this?

```
$some_mixed_array = array( 998, 6, 430 );
function custom_sort( $array )
{
  // Sort it
  asort($array);

  // return sorted array
  return $array;
}

custom_sort( $some_mixed_array );

// returning: array( 6, 430, 998 )
```

This would also solve your issue:

```
$some_mixed_array = array( 998, 6, 430 );
echo '<pre>'.print_r($some_mixed_array, true).'</pre>';

asort($some_mixed_array); // <- BAM!

// returning: array( 6, 430, 998 )
echo '<pre>'.print_r($some_mixed_array, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: You should warn that these two solutions do two different things. The first one doesn't change the original array, while the second does. Plus, using `asort` on number-indexed array is pretty weird. You maintain the original keys, but you are unable to iterate it naturally. It loses its nature of pure array.

Comment: `sorted` is the name of the function python uses

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, your best bet is to create a custom function.  However, in order to maintain flexibility with the future of PHP, I would use a [variadic function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). Essentially, you set your function to accepts whatever parameters are passed to it, and pass them through to the actual `sort()` function. Done this way, you can use whatever optional parameters exist for the standard function you're putting the wrapper around -- even if those parameters change in the future.

```php
function mysort( ...$params ) {
    sort( ...$params );
    return $params[0];
}
```

UPDATE: Same functionality, but somewhat easier to understand:

```php
function mysort( $array, ...$params ) {
    sort( $array, ...$params );
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP7, you can feed your input array to an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403) if you like one-liners. This will not mutate the original array, but return the mutated version of a copy of the original.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RHIFu))

```
$some_mixed_array = [998, 6, 430];

var_export(
    (function($v) { sort($v); return $v; })($some_mixed_array)
);
```

- `(function($v) { sort($v); return $v; })` is the closure.
- `($some_mixed_array)` is the single parameter inside the function signature.

`sort()` will not preserve the array's keys after sorting.
`asort()` will preserve the array's keys after sorting.

---

Of if you prefer brevity and don't mind using a ternary condition, you can enjoy PHP's arrow function syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Bc6Bg))

```
var_export(
    (fn($v) => sort($v) ? $v : $v)($some_mixed_array)
);
```