# Sort array values but do not change the original key order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
  '5' => 2,
  '6' => 3,
  '7' => 10,
  '8' => 1
);
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
$array = array(
  '5' => 1,
  '6' => 2,
  '7' => 3,
  '8' => 10
);
```

The keys should stay the same but the values should be ordered ascending. With `sort()` the keys will be deleted and replaced with keys starting at 0. `asort()` will order the values as I want but it will maintain the key association.

I tried `sort()`, `usort()`, `asort()` but none of these seem to be the ordering function that I need.
Do I have to sort manually or is there a function I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the keys of your array using [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), sort the values using [`sort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and then combine the keys back with the sorted values using [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$array = array(
'5' => 2,
'6' => 3,
'7' => 10,
'8' => 1
);  
$keys = array_keys($array);
sort($array);
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 10
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ddhGH)

Answer (score 0):

You can segregate the `sort()` call from the global scope by trapping it inside an anonymous function call.  As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75290787/2943403).

This performs the same action as Nick's answer but does not declare globally scoped variables, does not modify the original array, and can be written as one line.  I'll admit that it is a less readable variation.

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/4t))

```
var_export(
    array_combine(
        array_keys($array),
        (fn($v) => sort($v) ? $v : $v)($array)
    )
);
```